# How to remove the new required fields from the checkout page address in Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2.4

I have set up a virtual product store in Magento 2.4, where I do not require users to fill in address information during purchase. How can I remove the required fields from the checkout page address and disable server-side validation of address fields before submitting the order? Please provide instructions on how to disable this validation."

Who can help me? Thank you very much！

Comment: If your quote is virtual, it will not require the shipping address. But, it will require billing address. Please, what are fields you want to remove validation? I think you can search "disable required field validator checkout magento 2" and you will see some answers.

Comment: I need to delete First Name,  Last Name ,Street Address  , Zip/Postal Code,  Country  State/Province

Comment: I've hidden the shipping adress, firstbname lastname fields on the front end, but the back end still needs to validate when I click place orderd. How do I get around this verification? I do not want to change the required properties of the fields in the property sheet, because my other payment method requires required fields, and the other payment method does not require required fields

Comment: Please check your product is virtual product or not.

Comment: Yes, it's a virtual product

Answer (score 0):

Try these all step they will usefull for you

1. Override the checkout layout file:

In your custom theme or module, create the following directory path if it doesn't exist:

**app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Checkout/layout**

Create a file named **checkout_index_index.xml** in the above directory.

2. Edit the **checkout_index_index.xml** file and add the following code to remove the required attribute from the address fields.

> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0"?>
>
> <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
>     <body>
>         <!-- Remove the required attribute from address fields -->
>         <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
>             <arguments>
>                 <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
>                     <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
>                         <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
>                             <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
>                                 <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
>                                     <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
>                                         <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
>                                             <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
>                                                 <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
>                                                     <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
>                                                         <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
>                                                             <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
>                                                                 <!-- Remove the required attribute from specific fields -->
>                                                                 <item name="street" xsi:type="array">
>                                                                     <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
>                                                                         <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
>                                                                             <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
>                                                                         </item>
>                                                                     </item>
>                                                                 </item>
>                                                                 <!-- Add more fields to remove required attributes if needed -->
>                                                             </item>
>                                                         </item>
>                                                     </item>
>                                                 </item>
>                                             </item>
>                                         </item>
>                                     </item>
>                                 </item>
>                             </item>
>                         </item>
>                     </item>
>                 </argument>
>             </arguments>
>         </referenceBlock>
>     </body>
> </page>
> ```

3. Save the file and clear the Magento cache.

After making these changes, the address fields on the checkout page should no longer be marked as required.

*Please note* that modifying core files directly is not recommended, so it's always better to use a custom theme or module to override the necessary files and make these changes.

**HOPE THIS IS USEFUL TO YOU**